# Логика обновления присутствия скидки на товаре в базе данных MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Я стеснялся спросить данный вопрос. Пожалуйста не судите строга что я спрашиваю о глупостях.
Меня просто сильно мучает вопрос и пугает.

Есть товары, и у товаров в базе данных есть цена, т.е отдельная таблица с ценами на товары. И прямо там-же есть:

1. **скидка - (в процентах)**
2. **время скидки в unix**
3. **true/false (нужно ли оно или нет не знаю) - обозначает установлена ли скидка**

И например я вывожу товар, только со скидками, я для этого делаю запрос на таблицу с ценами, вывожу только те цены у которых есть true, и беру все что нужно и id товара что бы потом привязать.

Привязываю я значит товары к этим ценам/скидкам - делая еще 1 запрос только к товаров что бы получить имя и так-же id.
Потом связываю товары с ценами.

Вот представьте, вывелись товары, скидка стоит, имя так-же. И сделал я например время когда кончается скидка. И вот как обновлять товар со скидкой? Т.е если прошло время и у товара нет уже скидки, то он не должен отобразится.

Я думаю так, просто проверять перед отображением товара со скидкой на срок годности этой скидки. Т.е если скидка уже давно прошла по времени, то просто не добавлять товар и сразу же сделать запрос к этому товару на счет обновления данных таких как: скидка, время скидки (на ноль), с true обновить на false.

Я думаю что это не правильно. Потому что у меня есть еще запрос на вывод просто товаров, там должны быть и со скидками, и без скидок и получается я должен делать проверку каждый раз и каждый раз обновлять. Лично мне, именно мне, такой способ не удобный. Но возможно вы убедите меня что так лучше всего, и не как не обойтись.

*В общем то, подскажите мне, правильно ли я делаю все? Можно ли как то другим способ обновлять товар со скидкой? Может ли стоит сделать по другому базу данных с ценами?*

Comment: а время начала скидки не нужно? какая-нить черная пятница - с 10 по 15 число?

Comment: По моему вы все делаете не так. Т.е. по структуре БД особых замечаний нет, правда назначение true/false не понятно, если есть дата окончания скидки (ее кстати лучше сделать не unixtime, а нормальным полем типа datetime). Но вот с логикой работы, получаем некие id, потом по ним делаем еще один запрос ... Все данные из БД всегда получаются одним запросом, вне зависимости от количества таблиц и необходимой логики. В запросе выполняете join товаров с ценами, если дата окончания скидки < now() то скидку игнорируете...

Comment: А выборка всех товаров или только со скидкой это лишь наличие дополнительных условий в фразе where запроса. Для всех она не нужна, а если хотим только со скидкой то добавляем явно условие `discount_time > now()` (все где время уже прошло и все у которых скидка NULL в результат не попадут)

Comment: @splash58 оу, об этом я не думал. Я просто делал что бы можно установить на свой товар скидку, а например скидки у всех товаров с 10 - 15 числа не думал.

Comment: @Mike спасибо за ответ. Вижу вы стараетесь мне помочь. Спасибо.
У меня есть отдельная база с ценами, и именно у них есть скидка. Поэтому я другого способа не придумал кроме чем брать сначала цены (у которых есть и id товаров) и получаю id товаров делая после запрос к этим же самым товаров по id. С join я понял, но не знал!!! Спасибо! Я даже где то делаю 4 запроса одним разом. А вот что означает `< now()` ? Можете пожалуйста уточнить?

Comment: Я имею ввиду его как то можно сразу же в запросе делать? Или после вывода данных фильтровать? Наверное я вас правильно понял.

Comment: `now()` это функция mySql дающая текущую дату/время (в виде типа datetime). Собственно поэтому я и рекомендую в БД окончание скидки держать то же в datetime что бы их можно было спокойно сравнивать.

Comment: И да, любую фильтрацию всегда лучше делать на стороне базы данных, перегонка данных на клиента достаточно дорогая операция. И если что вопроса "можно ли отфильтровать на стороне БД" не бывает, может быть только вопрос "как" :)

Comment: @Mike я немного не понял все таки. Спасибо за объяснения конечно, но что означает на стороне БД? Т.е на стороне сервера? В php коде? Или вы говорите о том, делать все одним запросом? Или все таки бд и сервер одно и тоже. Возможно я вас не правильно понял.

Comment: На стороне БД, это в MySQL запросе (желательно в одном). что то вроде `select ... from цены C join Товары T on T.id=C.товар_id where C.discount_time > now()` дает товары со скидками, например.

Comment: @Mike я блин очень вам благодарен! Я не силен в mysql, и не знал что так можно делать. Спасибо вам большое. Теперь все понял, буду делать так как вы сказали

Comment: В последнем запросе ошибка, там конечно `<`, а не `>`. Ну я думаю разберетесь, тут действительно главное знать о том факте, что SQL это мощный язык, позволяющий сделать с данными практически что угодно и при этом в одном запросе. Пробегитесь для начала по https://sql-academy.org/ru/guide узнаете много интересного :)

Comment: @Mike спасибо вам. Я просто думал можно брать данные с таблиц по каким то условиям, а тут такое огого.